# Simulink integrator in library Python

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

i have a question, about for the block the simulink integrator, i looking for  alternative in python with scipy or other library, please.

Integer block ----> Scipy Python or other

Comment: Hi @May, please try to put as much context to your question as you can. Note stackoverflow is more focus to programming questions. Have a look at this guidelines for a better chance to get your question answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> num = [1]
>>> den = [1,0]
>>> integrator_tf = signal.TransferFunction(num, den)
```